# What is the 2SLS bias with a zero first stage in instrument analysis

Tags: self-study, instrumental-variables, treatment-effect, 2sls

[image]
I am trying to understand the impact in the IV estimate when zero coefficient is obtained in the first stage.

Comment: Hey Chris, welcome to the site. When asking homework questions, folks around here are a lot happier if you include the "self-study" tag, and if you tell us a little bit about what you find difficult or confusing as well as what you've been thinking/trying so far.

Comment: Thank you, John. I think α1 is 0. I am not sure how γ1 change or does not change. Then the IV effect is γ1/α1. No matter γ1  change or not, dividing by zero (or near zero) makes the estimate infinite. Is it even worse than OLS or close to the estimate of OLS?